# Variável viagem se mantém em 1 no banco de dados do Firebase, quando botão é pressionado, ao invés de somar mais 1 ao banco

Tags: java, android-studio, firebase

Olá, por algum motivo a variável viagem não está acrescentando mais 1 ao campo Viagens no Firebase, quando o botão pegLoc é pressionado, poderiam me ajudar?, Segue abaixo código:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private EditText edtUsuario;

```
private Button pegLoc;
FirebaseDatabase database;
DatabaseReference mDatabase;
Placa placa;
int viagem = 0;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    pegLoc = findViewById(R.id.btnPegarLoc);
    edtUsuario = findViewById(R.id.edtUsuario);

    placa = new Placa();

    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    mDatabase = database.getReference("localização");

    trocarTelas();
}

private void trocarTelas() {

    pegLoc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(edtUsuario.getText().toString().toUpperCase())) {

                edtUsuario.setError("Insira o Nome do Usuário");
                edtUsuario.requestFocus();

            } else {

                viagem = viagem + 1;

                placa.setPlaca(edtUsuario.getText().toString());

                mDatabase.child("Dados da Viagem").child("loc_Status_Viagem").setValue("Iniciada");

                mDatabase.child("Viagens").child(placa.getPlaca()).setValue(viagem);
                mDatabase.child("Dados da Viagem").child("Placa").setValue(placa.getPlaca());

                mDatabase.child("Dados da Viagem").child("loc_Hora").setValue(AppUtil.getHoraAtual());
                mDatabase.child("Dados da Viagem").child("loc_Data").setValue(AppUtil.getDataAtual());

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Localizacao.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }


     });
    }

}
```

Comment: A pergunta n ta mt clara, entao me diga uma coisa, quando vc clica no botao, o sistema consegue cai no else? para realizar o +1?

Comment: Simm, troca de tela e tudo, porém, sempre que clico para obter a localização, ele mantém em 1, no firebase, ao invés de somar mais 1

Comment: Os demais dados sao alterados corretamente? ous os outros tbm n mudam no firebase?

Comment: Sim, todos alteram normalmente, só esse em específico não se altera

Comment: Pelo q to vendo, o problema é q vc tem q primeiro atualizar a placa, Tenta inverter as linhas mDatabase.child("Viagens").child(placa.getPlaca()).setValue(viagem); e mDatabase.child("Dados da Viagem").child("Placa").setValue(placa.getPlaca());

Comment: Continua a mesma coisa : /

Comment: Posta a estrutura do teu firebase

Comment: placa.setPlaca(edtUsuario.getText().toString());

                mDatabase.child("Dados da Viagem").child("loc_Status_Viagem").setValue("Iniciada");

                mDatabase.child("Viagens").child(placa.getPlaca()).setValue(viagem);
                mDatabase.child("Dados da Viagem").child("Placa").setValue(placa.getPlaca());

                mDatabase.child("Dados da Viagem").child("loc_Hora").setValue(AppUtil.getHoraAtual());
                mDatabase.child("Dados da Viagem").child("loc_Data").setValue(AppUtil.getDataAtual());

Comment: Não Paulo, posta na pergunta como o seu banco firebase está estruturado

Comment: Pronto coloquei

Answer (score 0):

Ainda fiquei em duvida sobre algumas coisas, mas veja só.

Dentro do "Dados da Viagem" vc tem o atributo Placa e dentro de Viagem vc um atrubuto com nome fixo q seria uma placa pelo q to vendo.

O problema é que o codigo abaixo atualiza a placa q ta dentro de Dados da Viagem, porem a placa q tem no Viagem é fixo.

```
mDatabase.child("Dados da Viagem").child("Placa").setValue(placa.getPlaca());
```

Ou seja, se vc por o seguinte código, deve funcionar:

```
mDatabase.child("Viagens").child("hz123").setValue(viagem);
```

Comment: Não é fixo, esse hz123 é a placa que eu digitei, ai o app pega a placa digitada (placa.getPlaca()) e coloca o que deveria ser a soma (viagem), por isso o hz123, porém mesmo com um campo fixo, ele também não soma, no caso a linha que que você analisou é apenas para salvar a placa nos dados da viagem, onde vai ter a localização em tempo real etc, alinha certa é       mDatabase.child("Viagens").child(placa.getPlaca()).setValue(viagem);

Answer (score 0):

você pode usar o seguinte método para incremantar 1 automaticamente pelo banco de dados.

```
firebase.database.ServerValue.increment(1)
```